# Finding the Length of the Longest Substring without repeating characters

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I kind of have an understanding of this algorithm as a whole, but how is Math.max being used to output the correct substring?

And how is the check repetition function actually checking each individual character for the match?

```
public class Solution {
    public int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {
        
         int n = s.length();
         int res = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                for(int j = i; j < n; j++){
                    if(checkRepetition(s,i,j)){
                        res = Math.max(res, j - i + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        return res;
    }
    
    private boolean checkRepetition(String s,int start,int end){
        int []chars = new int [128];
        
            for(int i = start; i <= end; i++){
                char c = s.charAt(i);
                chars[c]++;
                
                if(chars[c] > 1){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: res is zero when you start. Each time you analyze a substring, you re-assign it between the maximum of itself and the length of the analyzed substring. Hence res will always be increasing, from 0 to the longest substring, and that's what you return at the end of the iteration.

Comment: `checkRepetition` is a poor choice of method name. If it returns `true` does it mean it has found repetitions or it has no repetitions? I can't tell from the name; I can only tell by studying the code. It should be named `hasAllCharactersUnique`. Note also that it will crash with any characters with code larger than 127.

Answer (score 1):

Your current, brute-force solution generates indices of each and every substring and then checks whether it contains repeated characters.

By doing so, you are repeating the same calculations multiple time. Instead of revisiting the same parts of the string over and over, we can perform this check only once and then reuse the results.

I don't know if there are some constraints regarding the input in this challenge, but creation of an array of length `128` seems fishy because it exceeds the range of digits and lower-case/upper-case English letters. If you print on the console characters that correspond to let's say `0`, `10` and `127` you will not see anything meaningful on the console.

And overall time complexity is quadratic **O(n ^ 2)** (considering the time complexity of the method `checkRepetition()` to be constant because it can perform at most `128` iterations).

This problem can be solved in a linear time **O(n)**.

And it doesn't require any assumptions. The algorithm introduced below is based on the suggestion by *@Andrey B. Panfilov* provided in the comments.

To find the longest substring not containing characters that are repeated withing the substring, we need to iterate over the given string and store previously encountered characters for a current non-repeated substring. For that, we can use a `HashSet` (denoted as `seen`).

We also need to maintain an index pointing to the beginning of the current substring (denoted as `left`).

While iterating, we are trying to incorporate every new character to the current substring, and if `seen.add()` would return `false` that means that we've hit a duplicate, and it means that we've done with the previous substring. Now we need to move the `left` index to the right to position one index beyond the previous occurrence of the character at the end of the current substring (at the index `right`). While moving the `left` index we also have to remove corresponding characters `str.charAt(left)` from the set.

To store the maximum length of the non-repeated substring we need to maintain a variable which has to be updated at the end of each iteration.

That's how it can be implemented:

```
public static int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String str) {
    
    Set<Character> seen = new HashSet<>();
    
    int left = 0;
    int maxSub = 0;
    
    for(int right = 0; right < str.length(); right++) {
        char next =  str.charAt(right);
        
        if (!seen.add(next)) {
            while (str.charAt(left) != next) {
                seen.remove(str.charAt(left++));
            }
            left++;
        }
        
        maxSub = Math.max(right + 1 - left, maxSub);
    }
    return maxSub;
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(lengthOfLongestSubstring(""));              // 0
    System.out.println(lengthOfLongestSubstring("a"));             // 1
    System.out.println(lengthOfLongestSubstring("aa"));            // 1
    System.out.println(lengthOfLongestSubstring("abc"));           // 3
    System.out.println(lengthOfLongestSubstring("abccb"));         // 3
    System.out.println(lengthOfLongestSubstring("abccfghijklhl")); // 8
}
```

*Output:*

```
0   // ""
1   // "a"
1   // "aa"
3   // "abc"
3   // "abccb"
8   // "abccfghijklhl"
```

Comment: You are doing the same mistake twice (for `abcabcbb` your code returns 0): do not precompute `frequency map`, the idea is following: keep two pointers (`left` and `right`), use one of them (`right`) to traverse string from left to right and store information about characters you have seen in `set`, if some character have appeared twice start moving the second pointer (`left`) to the right till `str.charAt(left)` (!not `left`) and remove information about every character seen from `set`, `right - left + 1` is a potential candidate

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Yes, I've revisited the original code the approach you've described reflect its intention correctly. Because the problem was poorly worded, I've understood the problem in the wrong way (characters not repeated in the whole given string).

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov I've implemented the logic that you've described. If you had an intention to post your own answer, let me know - I'll remove it.

Answer (score 0):

*but how is Math.max being used to output the correct substring?*

Math.max is used to only get the maximum length and not the substring itself. To get the maximum length substring you need to create a string variable and update it accordingly as:

```
if (j-i+1 > res) {
   res = j-i+1
   maxString = s.subsring(i, j+1)
}
```

*And how is the check repetition function actually checking each individual character for the match?*

Look at `int[] chars = new int[128]` and `chars[c]++`

The second part increments the number of times a character occurs in a string.

For example in your input string lets say the character 'z' appears twice then the `chars` array at the location 122 is incremented because the character 'z' is equivalent to integer 122 in ascii table. So if chars[122] > 1, then there is a repetition of 'z'. Simple. That's what the next block

```
if(chars[c] > 1){
   return false;
}
```

is doing.

Comment: Maybe one should say that the `int[] chars` array is used as a simple map, where the `char c` acts as a key. This also tells us that the string is supposed to contain only 7 bit ASCII characters (otherwise `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` might be thrown).